# Index of List in Scala

Tags: scala, indexing, lambda

I'm new in Scala.

For example, I have a List like

`val s = List(5, 11, 15, 7)`

and I need a lambda function to create a new list of the indexes of the elements that are more than 10. I can not use the language Scala libraries or functions. Only standard Scala opportunities.

How can I calculate the indices of these elements? Thank you!

Comment: Your homework...?

Comment: @groenhen nearly)

Comment: How does it help to have other people provide answers to what is clearlt either a self-assigned or actual course assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
   val lambda = (list: List[Int]) => {

  def filterList(l : List[Int], condition : Int, index: Int, acc: List[(Int, Int)]) : List[(Int, Int)] = l match {
    case List() => acc
    case h::tail =>
      if (h > condition) filterList( tail, condition, index + 1, (index, h) :: acc )
      else filterList( tail, condition, index + 1, acc )
  }

  filterList(list, 10, 0, List() )
}

val r = lambda( s )
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can not use built-in functions (such as zipWithIndex)

Comment: Just updated, I would assume you need to replaced condition with some function so this will be higher-order function

Comment: I would make an assumption what "lambdas" is not so relevant, as you can reuse code above as a template for lambdas.

Comment: Can we create a lambda function like `val filterList: List[Int] => List[Int] = {...}`?

Comment: Yes, you can do this, just update code. I've just wrapped this function into lambda body as helper function etc. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/anonymous_functions.htm

Answer (score 0):

Well... there are may ways to solve this.

First lets see the more wide-spread "imperative"-like solution with `var`,

```
val lambda = (list: List[Int]) => {
  var indexList = List.empty[Int]
  var i = 0
  for (elem <- list) {
    if (elem > 10) indexList = i +: indexList
    i = i + 1 
  }
  indexList.reverse
}
```

Now... we can look at a bit more "functional-like" recursive approach,

```
val lambda = (list: List[Int]) => {
  def _inner(list: List[Int], index: Int, indexList: List[Int]) = {
    list match {
      case Nil => indexList
      case elem :: tail => {
        if (elem > 10) _inner(tail, index + 1, index +: indexList)
        else _inner(tail, index + 1, indexList)
      }
    }
  }

  _inner(list, 0, List.empty[Int]).reverse
}
```

Comment: It's funny you call a *named method* a *lambda* :)